# Получение выборки из таблицы по нескольким условиям pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, обработка-данных, фильтрация

Есть таблица в формате csv, из неё нужно получить количество значений удовлетворяющих условию: в столбце TARGET равные нулю и в столбце значения MIP > 82, но меньше 84.
Такое выражение не работает:

```
report[report.TARGET == 0] & report[report.MIP >= 82] & report[report.MIP <= 84]
```

Как сделать выборку по нескольким значениям?

Comment: А в каком смысле "не работает"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция `np.logical_and`. Эта функция принимает строго два аргумента, поэтому есть два варианта для конъюнкции трёх выражений:

вариант 1: `report[np.logical_and(report.TARGET == 0, np.logical_and(report.MIP >= 82,report.MIP <= 84))]`

вариант 2: `report[np.logical_and.reduce((report.TARGET == 0, report.MIP >= 82,report.MIP <= 84))]`

Answer (score 2):

Лично я предпочитаю использовать "SQL-подобный" [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), потому, что код получается коротким и легкочитаемым:

```
res = report.query("""TARGET == 0 and 82 <= MIP <= 84""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вообще-то тоже должно работать:

```
report[(report.TARGET == 0) & (report.MIP >= 82) & (report.MIP <= 84)]
```

Обратите внимание на круглые скобки, они обязательны, иначе `Pandas` выдаёт ошибку, которая начинающим пандоводам непонятна.